# graph is upside down

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to draw a graph from my data, but the y axis starts from the highest value and decreases... I need help. Here is my code and plot

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


f = open("/Users/danielhankim/normalized_degree_distribution.txt", 'r')
data = f.readlines()
x = np.arange(1., 72., 1)



plt.plot(data, '.')
#plt.xscale('log')
#plt.yscale('log')
plt.xlabel('k')
plt.ylabel('P(k)')
plt.show(block=False)

f.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you include some of the distribution.txt file?

Comment: Also you can use plt.gca().invert_yaxis() for a quick fix.

Comment: Note that your y-axis labels aren’t actually inverted; they’re entirely out of order. Look at the first five labels, starting from the top.

Comment: @rassar Is there any specific way I can attach my txt file here?

Comment: @EdCottrell yeah, you're right.  I have no idea why this happened because there are no minus points in my data

Comment: @user10329622 Do you understand the duplicate? If not, feel free to ask about how to implement it.